# Python curses window flickering when resizing terminal

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

This is my first post on stack overflow so I hope I'm doing it properly.

I am currently working on a **Terminal User Interface for python applications**. I know that there are many ready-to-use libraries such as npyscreen out there, but I wantend to create one as programming excercice. In particular, I wanted to to play with some architectural patterns to learn them.

All that said, I'm currently facing several problems with **python curses library**, that I'm using as low level interface to the terminal.

The problems arise when I try to resize my terminal. As you can see from the code (see below), I handle the terminal resizing in the main loop, **invoking the getmaxyx()() method of my curses window** and redrawing what is on the screen accordingly.

**The problem is that the screen seems to flicker when I try to resize the terminal.**

Moreover, my "curses application" works fine on MacOS but **totally crashes on windows** (even after installing windows curses).

To handle that I tried to re-write the low-level interfice by using the **blessed** library. It **solved the windows crashing problem**, but the flickering still remains.

I can not figure out what the problem is.

Fore those wishing to help me, here follows the **github page** of the project: [Terminal GUI on GitHub](https://github.com/EmaPrn/Terminal_GUI)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With *curses*, there's (at least) 3 things to look for:

- ncurses can handle `SIGWINCH` (PDCurses may not)
- some Python configurations interfere with ncurses receiving `SIGWINCH`.  If your program never receives `KEY_RESIZE` (which it's not checking for...), then it's time to file a bug report for Python to get that fixed.
- some programs don't actively read keyboard input (and if `KEY_RESIZE` isn't ***read***, ncurses won't update the screensize.  That would make the program crash.

Comment: I tried to check for `KEY_RESIZE` in input with an `if k == curses.KEY_RESIZE`.
But, unfortunately, the final behavior does not change. 

Moreover, on windows, it still seems to draw "diagonally" when resizing